# Is there a way to calculate slope, intercept in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to calculate the slope, intercept in python pandas. For example , for the below dataframe, can we calculate / populate another column that calculates y = mx + c

```
date_range = pd.date_range(date(2021,11,7), date.today())
index = date_range 
value = np.random.rand(len(index))
historical = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_range, 'Sales' : value})

historical
Out[300]: 
          date     Sales    m     c     y = mx+c
0   2021-11-07  0.210038   ---   ---     ----
1   2021-11-08  0.918222   ---   ---     ----
2   2021-11-09  0.202677   ---   ---     ----
3   2021-11-10  0.620185   ---   ---     ----
4   2021-11-11  0.299857   ---   ---     ----
```

So m and c will be constant for each row here

Comment: can you provide an example output? the slope/intercept is an aggregation, do you want to perform a rolling fit?

Comment: What is the connection between the slope/intercept and the data? Are you trying to apply a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)?

Comment: Yeah Linear regression of the form y = mx + c

Comment: Edited my question. So basically , x is a Sales value of respective rows. m is the slope

Comment: can you provide a numerical example? not `---` All values will be identical?

Comment: yes.  m and c are constant for each rows..... I do not know the exact number so not able to put here